# Why would a new Unit Test project not be included when we run all tests in solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

We recently separated some code into its own assembly and consequently moved the related unit tests into their own test assembly. Now none of those tests run, they don't show up in the tests lists and if you select one test and run all tests in current context it just starts running all the other unit tests as if you're not in a unit test method.

Where should I start looking for solutions?

We're running VS2010 Premium & it's a .NET 4.0 assembly using MS Unit Tests.

Comment: I assume you are using MS Unit test?

Comment: Sorry, yes we're using MS Unit Test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio looks at special attributes in the project file to determine whether it should inspect the Types in that assembly for tests.

Check [here on how to manually create your MSTest project.](http://www.bryancook.net/2009/12/manually-creating-ms-test-project.html)